React Antd v5 css in js and legacy themes support - a gradual move from less to css in js
To start off, I've read many posts regarding this topic with creation dates spanning several years and couldn't find a definitive answer to this question. So I apologize upfront if this is a duplicate.
I am transitioning an Antd v4 application to Antd v5. I'm aware that v5 doesn't support LESS / CSS anymore and that the move has been made to CSS in JS, which is fine by me, I actually love this concept. There are a couple of problems that I'm facing with my move:

First is that we are using a huge base theme-dark and theme-light CSS, with all the base styles in them
From this problem comes the second one, and it is the lack of time to do the complete move at once

So my goal would be to have my original CSS themes (ugly as they are) for now as the base, and then gradually upgrade the components' styles to include the themes and everything. When I manually delete all the dynamically inserted styles from Antd v5 (in the browser developer console), this actually fixes my styles and it looks like it could work (before they get reinserted).
Now, my question is, is it somehow possible to set priorities, such that the Antd components' styles are overridden by the base themes' CSS, which are then overridden by the CSS in js of my custom components? (Keep in mind that our CSS themes contain full and styling for light and dark.) This would then override the styles I don't want and allow me to move the styles at my own pace from the themes to CSS in js.
Thanks for any info on this topic.
